# How to use drupal_add_html_head() to add the same metatag multiple times?

Tags: 7, social-network, meta-tags

I have a node which has multiple images attached to it. And each image should also be printed in a `<meta property="og:image" content="image_url" />` metatag. I have tried to use `drupal_add_html_head()` for each image in a `template_preprocess_page()`, but only the last image is printed as metatag.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
...
    // add multiple og:image tags
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $element = array(
            '#tag' => 'meta',
            '#attributes' => array(
                "property" => "og:image",
                "content" => $image,
            ),
        );
        drupal_add_html_head($element,'facebook_share_image');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tags are stored by key, so using a different key for each should do the trick:

```
$delta = 0;
foreach ($images as $image) {
    $element = array(
        '#tag' => 'meta',
        '#attributes' => array(
            "property" => "og:image",
            "content" => $image,
        ),
    );
    drupal_add_html_head($element,'facebook_share_image:' . $delta++);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For apple's favicons you can use something like this:

```
function mytheme_page_attachments_alter(array &$page) {
      $apple_sizes = [57, 60, 72, 76, 114, 120, 144, 152, 180, 192];
    
      foreach ($apple_sizes as $size) {
        $favicon = [
          '#type' => 'html_tag',
          '#tag' => 'link',
          '#attributes' => [
            'rel' => 'apple-touch-icon',
            'sizes' => $size . 'x' . $size,
            'href' => '/themes/gov_pt/apple-icon-' . $size . 'x' . $size . '.png'
          ],
        ];
        $page['#attached']['html_head'][] = [$favicon, 'apple-touch-icon' . $size];
      }
}
```